# finding the free energy of a van der waals gas (integration)

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, rational-functions

I have the following integral,

$\int{ \frac{-nrtV}{(v-nb)^{2}} dV}$

could anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If $u = V - nb$, then $du = dV$, so

\begin{align}\int \frac{-nrtV}{(V - nb)^2}\, dV &= \int \frac{-nrt(u + nb)}{u^2}\, du\\
& = -nrt \int \left(\frac{1}{u} + \frac{nb}{u^2}\right)\, du \\
&= -nrt\left(\log|u| -\frac{nb}{u}\right) + C\\
&= -nrt\left(\log|V - nb| - \frac{nb}{V - nb}\right) + C.
\end{align}

Comment: Why doesn't integration by parts work?

Comment: @user2804865 it does work. Why do you think it doesn't?

Comment: I did it and it gave me the wrong answer.

Comment: @user2804865 since you didn't show your work, I cannot see where (or if) you made a mistake. However, there might be a chance that your answer differs from mine by a constant. This is ok since $C$ is an arbitrary constant.